# azure database most significant differences in comparison to aurora mysql (aws manged databse)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, amazon-aurora

i would like to know the main differences , aproaches needed to be taken as devops for using  azure manged database in comparison to AWS rds https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraMySQL.html 
i found this 
https://medium.com/@lakshmanLD/comparison-of-mysql-across-aws-azure-and-gcp-19af2d208d9a
which point out some differences , the most significantly for my team is that Manual Backup (DB snapshots can be created anytime manually) is not supports in Azure , is there any other main / big differences ? some different dev-ops approaches that needed to be taken ?

Comment: There is a MySQL database as a service in Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/

Comment: this the Azure alternative for aurora ?

Comment: it can be one alternative is you want to use MySql, if Microsoft SQL Server is also good for you you can use Azure SQL: https://azure.microsoft.com/hu-hu/services/sql-database/ here is a comparison article: https://medium.com/@lakshmanLD/comparison-of-mysql-across-aws-azure-and-gcp-19af2d208d9a

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're already in the Azure ecosystem, then you have a variety of DB services from the Azure catalog, and you should probably go with them. However, there are exceptions where customers run a hybrid infrastructure, between cloud providers. If thats something you have in mind, then the closest you can do is to provision an Aurora cluster in AWS and then setup your VPC to link it with your VPC/VPN in Azure. It's a bit non standard, and hence would be difficult to get good docs for it.

Comment: i am looking for the standard replacement , the most commonly usage

Comment: Well, then you would need to update your wording in the question and the title. It says "Is there a way of using Aurora in Azure" right now, which is what I was addressing.

Comment: update the question